# A technical problem on the contragredient representation in the context of locally compact totally disconnected groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\pi$ be an admissible representation of a locally compact totally disconnected group. I have a technical problem about the proof of

*$\pi$ is irreducible if and only if its contragredient is so*

given in 2.15(c) of the '76 article of Bernstein and Zelevinsky. There $\pi$ is assumed to have a nontrivial proper subrepresentation $E_1$, and it is asserted that the orthogonal complement of $E_1$ be a nontrivial proper subrepresentation of the contragredient, whence the result. What I cannot figure out is the nontriviality of this orthogonal complement. We simply have to find a nonzero smooth functional which vanishes on $E_1$; this shall follow from $E_1\neq E$ (as properness of the orthogonal complement follows from $E_1\neq 0$), but how?

Comment: The paper seems to be: http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1977_4_10_4_441_0  But I cannot find 2.15(c)??

Comment: That's the wrong B-Z paper. The right one is http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/B-Zel-RepsGL-Usp.pdf

Comment: @Faisal: Thanks! The spelling of Zelevinsky (or ..ii) defeated MathSciNet... 

Comment: No problem. When I started learning about the rep theory of p-adic groups I was told that a good basic reference is "the paper by Bernstein and Zelevinsky". Like you, I thought that meant http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1977_4_10_4/ASENS_1977_4_10_4_441_0/ASENS_1977_4_10_4_441_0.pdf because it was the first thing that showed up in my search. I was really confused until I realized that there was another (more appropriate) B-Z paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from two facts:

1. The complement $E_1^\perp$ of $E_1$ in $\tilde{E}$ is isomorphic to the contragredient of $E/E_1$.
2. If $V$ is admissible and nonzero then $\tilde{V}$ is nonzero (and admissible). For if $\tilde{V}=0$ then $V = \tilde{\tilde{V}} = 0$.

Comment: If I understand the question, the worry is about algebraic (=smooth) vectors-- here $x\in E$ is smooth if the stabilizer of $x$ for the $\pi$ action is an _open_ subgroup of $G$.  Could you say some words about this??

Comment: The contragredient is by definition the "smooth dual" representation (i.e. the subrep of the dual rep on the subspace of smooth vectors).

Comment: In symbols, $\tilde{V} = (V^\ast)^\infty$.

Comment: @Faisel: Sure!  But I think the original question wanted to know why there is an algebraic vector in the perp of $E_1$.  That is, your answer seemed a bit brief, given what the original question asked (so I think maybe it won't be easy to understand).  However, on a close reading of the original question, I see that $\pi$ is assumed "admissible".  I personally don't understand what implications this has, but it seems to imply lots of powerful things; so maybe one needs to fully understand this definition...??

Comment: As far as this question is concerned, admissibility is important because it gives us the equivalence $\tilde{\tilde{\pi}}=\pi$ (which I used in (2)). This equivalence doesn't hold for general inadmissible $\pi$. 

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that the monomorphism $\pi \to \widetilde{\widetilde{\pi}}$ is an isomorphism for admissible $\pi$, then you can see that $\pi \mapsto \widetilde{\pi}$ is a contravariant autoequivalence on the abelian category of admissible (smooth) representations. Thus it carries simple objects to simple objects.